# Unusable Response Body in WebSocket Reverse Proxy

Tags: http, go, websocket

Update: Go 1.12 added `httputil.ReverseProxy` support for WebSocket traffic. The answer to this question is now to upgrade your version of Go.

---

Go's [httputil.ReverseProxy](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#ReverseProxy) doesn't work for [WebSocket](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) traffic. The issues with it are detailed [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26937#issuecomment-419321249).  It looks like the fix/feature may be released in Go 1.12 (see "added this to the Go1.12 milestone" [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26937)).

As the fix/feature is not out yet, I am trying to write my own reverse proxy to solve the problem until it is released.  On my server, I wrote a simple [gorilla/websocket](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket) handler that upgrades the connection and then waits for a message from the client.

On my reverse proxy server, I wrote a reverse proxy handler based on the Go 1.12 change submission [here](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/146437/), especially the additions in [reverseproxy.go](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/146437/2/src/net/http/httputil/reverseproxy.go).  Here is the core of my reverse proxy handler, in relevant part:

```
outreq := r.WithContext(ctx)
if r.ContentLength == 0 {
    outreq.Body = nil
}
p.director(outreq)
outreq.Header = copyHeaders(browserHeaders)
setForwardHeader(r.RemoteAddr, outreq)
log.Infof("outreq URL is %+v", outreq.URL)

transport := http.DefaultTransport
res, err := transport.RoundTrip(outreq)
if err != nil {
    log.Errorf("RoundTrip(outreq) failed: %s", err)
}
log.Infof("Server response was %+v", res)

if res.StatusCode != http.StatusSwitchingProtocols {
    log.Errorf("Did not receive HTTP status 101 switchingn protocols: %d\n", res.StatusCode)
    return
}
if !hasUpgradeHeaders(res.Header) {
    log.Error("request does not contain upgrade headers")
    return
}
backConn, ok := res.Body.(io.ReadWriteCloser)
if !ok {
    log.Errorf("internal error: 101 switching protocols response with non-writable body: %v (%T)", res.Body, res.Body)
    return
}
```

When I try to connect a websocket from my browser, I get as far as that last if statement.  The type assertion of the response body to type `io.ReadWriteCloser` failed.  When I log the response I see this:

```
Server response was &{Status:101 Switching Protocols StatusCode:101 Proto:HTTP/1.1 
ProtoMajor:1 ProtoMinor:1 Header:map[Upgrade:[websocket] Connection:[Upgrade]
Sec-Websocket-Accept:[B1fWETPTtNo0bAHFWkFn2lAm9iw=]] Body:{} ContentLength:0 
TransferEncoding:[] Close:false Uncompressed:false 
Trailer:map[] Request:0xc000112100 TLS:<nil>}
```

The error log output is this:

`ERRO[0012] internal error: 101 switching protocols response with non-writable body: {} (http.noBody)`

Why am I getting `http.noBody` in the response body rather than something implementing the `io.ReadWriteCloser` interface?  How can I resolve the issue so that I can proceed to [hijack](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Hijacker) the connection and facilitate communication between the browser and the server?

### Update

I think I found the answer to the "why" question.  The latest release of Go does not include this line in persistConn's readLoop function in transport.go in the net/http package:

```
if resp.isProtocolSwitch() {
    resp.Body = newReadWriteCloserBody(pc.br, pc.conn)
}
```

[Source](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/131279/4/src/net/http/transport.go#1862)

Compare to current [here](https://golang.org/src/net/http/transport.go).

Any ideas for how to resolve?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to make ReverseProxy work?

Comment: @GregGilley Yes, I wrote a custom, low-level (e.g. `io.Copy`) WebSocket reverse proxy that worked well. I can't share it because my employer owns the code and it's not open source. However I have since been able to replace that with the standard `httputil.ReverseProxy` and that is also working well.

Comment: My problem was my RoundTrip handler. I was printing out the buffer for debugging and it caused the "non-writable buffer" problem. Thanks for replying!